# Minor xtick marked incorrectly?

Tags: pgfplots, ticks, axis

I am using the following code to plot same experimental data, and for some reason, minor xticks appear to be misaligned from their intended position. As the x value incrases, there is more and more space between minor and major marks even though every second minor mark should perfectly align with a major one. Why is this happening? Could it have something to do with the small value of minor xtick step (1e-3)?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width = 11cm, height = 7cm,
    xmin = 0.000, xmax = 0.018, ymin = 2, ymax = 9,
    xtick = {0.000,0.002,...,0.016}, minor xtick = {0.000,0.001,...,0.018},
    ytick = {2,3,...,8}, minor ytick = {2.0,2.2,...,9},
    xlabel = $I\mbox{ }{[A]}$, ylabel = $U\mbox{ }{[V]}$,
    axis line style = thick, axis lines = middle,
    hide obscured x ticks = false, hide obscured y ticks = false,
    x tick label style = {/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision = 3, use comma, /tikz/.cd}, scaled x ticks = false,
    clip = false, grid = both,
    grid style = {line width=.1pt, draw=gray!20},
    major grid style = {line width = .2pt, draw = gray!50},
    enlargelimits = false,
    scale = 1,
  ]
  \addplot[color = black, thick, domain = 0.006:0.016]{-307.11*x+7.9911};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the following graph. Look at the x-axis closely.

[image]

Comment: yes this is expected. foreach lists use TeX arithmetic and that goes wrong in limited precision. Try giving the entries manually and it will go away. There is a duplicate about this somewhere on this site.

Comment: Adding manual entries, despite being a bit tedious, also works, thanks! I tried to find this error as not to post a duplicate question, but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

you define minor grid on unusual way. see changes (indicated by `<--- added` and with commented lines of code) in *mwe* below:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % not needed in this example
%\usepackage{tikz}          % loaded by pgfplots

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width = 11cm, height = 7cm,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 0.018,
    ymin = 2, ymax = 9,
    xtick = {0.000,0.002,...,0.016},
%    minor xtick, = {0.000,0.001,...,0.018},
%    ytick = {2,3,...,8},
    extra y ticks = {3,5,7}, % <--- added
%    minor ytick, = {2.0,2.2,...,9},
    xlabel = $I\mbox{ }{[A]}$, ylabel = $U\mbox{ }{[V]}$,
    axis line style = thick, axis lines = middle,
    x tick label style = {/pgf/number format/.cd,
                          fixed, fixed zerofill, precision = 3, use comma,
                          /tikz/.cd},
%    hide obscured x ticks = false,
%    hide obscured y ticks = false,
    scaled x ticks = false,
    minor x tick num=1, % <--- added
    minor y tick num=4, % <--- added
    grid = both,
    minor grid style = {densely dashed,very thin},
%    enlargelimits = false,
%    scale = 1,
  ]
  \addplot[color = black, thick, domain = 0.006:0.016]{-307.11*x+7.9911};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```